# No Wifi with Lubuntu 14.04 on HP Netbook

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I just installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a HP Mini 110 netbook but I can't get the Wifi to work. It works with other distro's like Linux Mint and Elementary OS but not with Lubuntu : no Wifi icon and impossible to configure Wifi through **Preferences > Network Connections** (the save button stays grayed out). I tried some solutions I found on the forum like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and configuring `nm-applet` but no change. Updating Lubuntu also didn't fix it. What could I try next?

Complete diagnostics through the wireless-script here: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10706923

Thanx in advance for any tips or suggestions!

Zendrik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dmesg portion of the script results shows that firmware is missing.  If you have a wired connection, in terminal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
Reboot and wifi should function

Comment: Nice. Wifi is up and running now. Thanx, Jeremy31, for the solution. :-)

Comment: Worked for me. And if you don't want to reboot you can restart the firmare with sudo modprobe -rv b43 && sudo modprobe -v b43